# how can i tell if a string contains ONLY digits and spaces in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, numbers, spaces, digits

I'm trying to write some script in python (using regex) and I have the following problem:

I need to make sure that a string contains ONLY digits and spaces but it could contain any number of numbers.

Meaning it should match to the strings:
"213" (one number), "123 432" (two numbers), and even "123 432 543 3 235 34 56 456 456 234 324 24" (twelve numbers).

I tried searching here but all I found is how to extract digits from strings (and the opposite) - and that's not helping me to make sure weather ALL OF THE STRING contains ONLY numbers (seperated by any amount of spaces).

Does anyone have a solution?

If someone knows of a class that contains all the special characters (such as ! $ # _ -) it would be excellent (because then I could just do [^A-Z][^a-z][^*special-class*] and therefore get something that don't match any characters and special symbols - leaving me only with digits and spaces (if I'm correct).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic regular expression would be

```
/^[0-9 ]+$/
```

However is works also if your string only contains space. To check there is at least one number you need the following

```
/^ *[0-9][0-9 ]*$/
```

You can try it on  [there](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5E%20%2a%5B0-9%5D%5B0-9%20%5D%2a%24&test_string=14%20&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Answer (score 17):

This code will check if the string only contains numbers and space character.

```
if re.match("^[0-9 ]+$", myString):
    print "Only numbers and Spaces"
```

Comment: ^ missing at the beginnig?

Comment: @mb14: no, re.match always starts at the beginning.

Comment: You can use it with or without the start anchor.

Comment: This matches also empty strings - replace `*` with `+`.

Comment: @Jon Thanks :) OP says `ONLY digits and spaces` :)

Comment: @thefourtheye Why not `if bool(re.search('^[0-9 ]+$', str)):` ?  =)

Comment: @hwnd That does the same thing and we don't explicitly have to convert the result to `bool` :)

Answer (score 1):

Well I'd propose something that does not use `regex`:

```
>>> s = "12a 123"
>>> to_my_linking = lambda x: all(var.isdigit() for var in x.split())
>>> to_my_linking(s)
False
>>> s = "1244 432"
>>> to_my_linking(s)
True
>>> a = "123 432 543 3 235 34 56 456 456 234 324 24"
>>> to_my_linking(a)
True
```

In case you're working the `lambda` is just a simple way to make a one liner function. If we wrote it using a `def`, then it would look like this:

```
>>> def to_my_linking(number_sequence):
...     return all(var.isdigit() for var in number_sequence.split())
...
```